# GNU make nested calls

Tags: bash, gnu-make

I need to find a way to avoid sub-calls to make to be done in parallel, and avoid getting the warning:
    make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.

I do have several make calls that run in parallel because the main make call runs with flag `-jN`with N>1
I receive the warning listed above and can see the Makefile and make call causing it.
However, I've tried to use several options provided in the gnu/make documentation and still cannot get the warning to go.

```
a)
+make -C $FOO $@

b)
make MAKEFLAGS= -C $FOO $@

c)
make -j1 -C $FOO $@

d)
.NOTPARALLEL:bar
```

I need the whole compilation to run without warnings (because they are treated as errors).
But the warning described above continues to appear.

Comment: What if you just don't call `make` recursively from your Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is coming from the invoked make, because it's getting certain jobserver-related flags via `MAKEFLAGS`.

To show this, we can reproduce the error message in a simple invocation of `make` like this:

```
make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j1
make: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
... other errors about those being bad file descriptors ...
```

Overriding `MAKEFLAGS` in the `make` command line isn't doing it, because that is being interpreted by the invoked `make`, after it has already received the `MAKEFLAGS` from the parent. But we can intercept the parent's environment variable via the external utility `env`:

```
yourtarget: yourprereq
        env MAKEFLAGS= make -j1 -C $FOO $@
```

With `env`, we have total control over what environment variables are seen by the nested `make`.

Comment: Do you actually need `env` or could you just do `MAKEFLAGS= make -j1 -C $FOO $@`?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that wouldn't work. It works for me without the `env`, since the whole thing is passed to the shell as a command. It's more efficient this way; one less "shim" process is involved.  In fact, we usually don't need `env` if we have a shell interpreter; only if we are dealing with raw `exec` mechanisms and their argument lists. That is, `env` lets us insert environment overrides if the only interface we are able to manipulate is an `argv` being passed down to a process that isn't a shell interpreter.

Comment: I started investigating this question with `env` purely as piece of syntax to try to fool make into not recognizing the executed command as a nested `make`.  That's a red-herring here, though.

Comment: Thanks @Kaz for the solution, works like a charm. No need for the env at all.